# South not Migrating django.contrib.admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-south

I have a Django project that's managed by South. I ran through the normal procedure when I first started the project:

- Install South
- Add South to INSTALLED_APPS
- Perform initial syncdb
- schemamigration --initial, followed by migrate myapp

Everything's been working fine and I've done several migrations since. Now I enabled the django admin portion of the site (INSTALLED_APPS, urls, etc.). When I tried adding a test user, I was received the following error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/add/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    
no such table: django_admin_log
```

I tried running `schemamigration myapp --auto` but it's telling me nothing's changed. I even tried running `convert_to_south django.contrib.admin`, as well as trying a fake migration, but I keep getting the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

second's answer is correct

> only apps that make use of south will be managed by south

so using south isn't a possible solution.

Your issue is that the syncdb thinks that the table for django_admin_log has already been created.

#### Solution

1. open your `django_content_type` table.
2. delete the record for the `name="log entry", app_label="admin", model="logentry"` content type.
3. run syncdb again

Answer (score 2):

only apps that make use of south will be managed by south

`django.contrib.admin` doesn't. instead you need another `syncdb` (it will leave any existing tables alone, so should be safe to run)

Comment: thanks, I was afraid of running syncdb cause I wasn't sure it was safe.